# How can I implement binary search in Substring in function and two values in Comparator?

Tags: java, binary-search

I have a problem about implementing binary search in substring. In my City object, there is a cityName variable as defined String. I want to enter any substring like "Sha" and it shows the result of "Sha". Except for this, there is a weight variable to sort descend city names. For example, the bigger weight value is at the top and the sort process is based on descending.

How can I do that? How can I add this to the `comparater` area?

Here is my City Object

```
public class City implements Serializable{
    private Integer cityWeight;
    private String cityName;
}
```

Here is my code snippet shown below.

// Not implement Binary Search

```
public static Integer[] searchByCharacters(List<City> list, String sub) {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        Collections.sort(list);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).getCityName().contains(sub))
                result.add(i);
        }
        return result.stream().toArray(Integer[]::new);
}
```

I want to implement binary search above the code snippet but it doesn't work.

```
public static Integer[] searchBySubStringCharacter(List<City> list, String sub) {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

        Comparator<City> comparator = new Comparator<City>() {
            public int compare(City node1, City node2) {
                boolean node1Contains = node1.getCityName().contains(sub);
                boolean node2Contains = node2.getCityName().contains(sub);
                if (node1Contains && !node2Contains) {
                    return 1;
                } else if (!node1Contains && node2Contains ) {
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        };

        Collections.sort(list, comparator);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            int index = Collections.binarySearch(list, new City(sub), comparator);
            if (index >= 0)
                result.add(i);
        }

        return result.stream().toArray(Integer[]::new);
    }
```

This code shows all city list and the result of binary search. How can I extract all city list from the result?

Comment: The existing answers may address your compilation issue but... what is the goal of this method?  It looks like you are going to sort the List, then find the index of the first match, then fill an array the size of the List with that value, and return that array.  I'm guessing this is not your goal.

Comment: @vsfDawg I editted my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`binarySearch` accepts the key to be searched for having type the class of the objects in the list,

```
public static <T> int binarySearch(List<? extends T> list, T key, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

So pass `City` object in `binarySearch`,

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
     int index = Collections.binarySearch(list, new City(sub), comparator);
     if (index >= 0)
        result.add(i);
}
```

Also if you are using java8+, you can use lambda for `Comparator`,

```
Comparator<City> comparator = (node1, node2) -> {
     boolean node1Contains = node1.getCityName().contains(sub);
     boolean node2Contains = node2.getCityName().contains(sub);
     if (node1Contains && !node2Contains) {
        return 1;
     } else if (!node1Contains && node2Contains ) {
        return -1;
     } else {
        return 0;
     }
};
```

Update: To sort based on the weight in case of a match you need to use `Integer.compare(node2.getCityWeight(), node1.getCityWeight())`,

Also iyou can not `binarySearch` with same comparator as you don't know the weight of the city you are searching. you can use Stream,

```
public static Integer[] searchBySubStringCharacter(List<City> list, String sub) {
  List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

  Comparator<City> comparator = (node1, node2) -> {
     boolean node1Contains = node1.getCityName().contains(sub);
     boolean node2Contains = node2.getCityName().contains(sub);
     if (node1Contains && !node2Contains) {
        return 1;
     } else if (!node1Contains && node2Contains ) {
        return -1;
     } else {
        return Integer.compare(node2.getCityWeight(), node1.getCityWeight());
     }
  };
  Collections.sort(list, comparator);

  return IntStream.rangeClosed(0, list.size() - 1)
          .filter(i -> list.get(i).getCityName().contains(sub))
          .boxed()
          .toArray(Integer[]::new);
}
```

Comment: I'll try your code but there is a problem. The result shows all cities and then the result of searchBySubStringCharacter.

Comment: The result all depends on your `comparator` logic.

Comment: there is a problem in for loop.

Comment: I've done my project and uploaded my github repository. There is a problem for seaching part. When I write "Moscow", it shows 2 results without showing 1 result. Can you check my project if you don't mind. https://github.com/Rapter1990/Binary-Search-Example

Answer (score 0):

You can add create city object from string and search like this:

```
  public static Integer[] searchBySubStringCharacter(List<City> list, String sub) {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

        Comparator<City> comparator = new Comparator<City>() {
            public int compare(City node1, City node2) {
                boolean node1Contains = node1.getCityName().contains(sub);
                boolean node2Contains = node2.getCityName().contains(sub);
                if (node1Contains && !node2Contains) {
                    return 1;
                } else if (!node1Contains && node2Contains) {
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        };

        Collections.sort(list, comparator);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            int index = Collections.binarySearch(list, new City(sub), comparator);
            if (index >= 0)
                result.add(i);
        }

        return result.stream().toArray(Integer[]::new);
    }
```

, or avoid creating city object every iteration and accept city as an argument

```
public static Integer[] searchBySubStringCharacter(List<City> list, City sub) {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

        Comparator<City> comparator = new Comparator<City>() {
            public int compare(City node1, City node2) {
                boolean node1Contains = node1.getCityName().contains(sub.getCityName());
                boolean node2Contains = node2.getCityName().contains(sub.getCityName());
                if (node1Contains && !node2Contains) {
                    return 1;
                } else if (!node1Contains && node2Contains) {
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        };

        Collections.sort(list, comparator);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            int index = Collections.binarySearch(list, sub, comparator);
            if (index >= 0)
                result.add(i);
        }

        return result.stream().toArray(Integer[]::new);
    }
```

Comment: the first one (public static Integer[] searchBySubStringCharacter(List<City> list, String sub))  get a full object list and the result of search like ("Sha").

Comment: there is a problem in for loop part.

Comment: I'm waiting for your response.

Comment: By the way, why do you need to use `BinarySearch` in this situation

Comment: Because the linear search will be good `O(n)` rather than the complexity of sort then apply search

Comment: I've done my project and uploaded my github repository. There is a problem for seaching part. When I write "Moscow", it shows 2 results without showing 1 result. Can you check my project if you don't mind. https://github.com/Rapter1990/Binary-Search-Example

Comment: sure, I will check it

Comment: How can I do the same process as ascending in weight part?

Comment: I have imported your project to the IDE and I will this case

Comment: okey. All city weights are ordered by descending. How can I write extra code in comparator part as ascending?

Comment: use this: `Integer.compare(node1.getCityWeight(), node2.getCityWeight())`

Comment: this process is valid for searchBySubStringCharacter . What about others function named for binarySearch and searchByCharacters

Comment: Let me check that